# query without prefixes in SPARQL

Tags: r, sparql

I have an entry level question which my book could not help with and I also confused a colleague. Can I use RDF without specifiying prefixes and how do I specificy the predicate in the SPARQL query?

I'm doing this in R's RRDF package but if I set up a store as

```
A=new.rdf(ontology=F)
add.triple(A,"Ian","sonOf","Daddy")
add.triple(A,"Ian","sonOf","Mummy")
add.triple(A,"Ian","likes","Chocolate")
```

I get the following message

```
## Error: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error
at line 1, column 40. Encountered: " " (32), after : "sonOf"
```

to the query

```
sparql.rdf(A, "select ?son ?parent where {?son sonOf ?parent}")
```

Can I use `sonOf` in this way? Do I have to set up my own Schema first? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Do I have to use prefixes if all my data resides on the same data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **rrdf** R package, the following syntax seemed to work:

```
library(rrdf)
D = new.rdf(ontology = F)
add.triple(D, "ian", "w:likes", "food")
add.triple(D, "ian", "w:hates", "homework")
sparql.rdf(D, "select ?child ?object where {?child <w:likes> ?object.}")
sparql.rdf(D, "select ?child ?object where {?child <w:hates> ?object.}")
```

You thus need to used the `<>` in the SPARQL calls but not calls to `add.triple()`. This seems obvious now but confused a few of us at the time.

Answer (score 4):

An RDF predicate is always a URI (technically, actually a IRI, but let's set that aside).

It can be specified as a prefixed name:

```
  namespace:sonOf
```

or an IRIRef, e.g:

```
  <http://my.namespace.com#sonOf>
```

but I don't think it can be given as a plain label like you are attempting.

If you use the prefixed name style, then the prefix must be defined and bound to a namespace, so that a valid URI can be constructed from your input.

(The formal grammar is given in the [SPARQL Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#QSynIRI).)

Comment: that is really useful. If I try that, it still does not work. Do I have to define anything at the URI I specify? I.e. in your example, is my.namespace.com actually used?

Comment: Well that URI has to actually be in your data, I'm not familiar with the package you are using so I don't know how it creates URIs when you create your data as shown in your question.  It's possible it is keeping the URIs relative in which case you should be able to use `<sonOf>` directly, if that doesn't work try dumping your data out to NTriples since that will require it to write out the URIs in full

Comment: is there a way to tell what all `namespace`s are available in a repository?  or is there a way to tell with which namespace a triple is associated?  please see [my recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854135/how-to-list-all-all-namespaces-in-virtuoso)

Answer (score 1):

i think you're asking about "blank" prefixes... if so:

when you define your prefixes, you can just say something like:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
```

which would then be used like:

```
?sub :sonOf ?obj
```