# How to list all all graphs in Virtuoso?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

When I go to `http://localhost:8890/sparql/`, there are two fields: `Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)` and `query`. How can I list what all graphs (that go in the former field) are available in my DB? The field is not mandatory and I can just run a query against all namespaces. But I would like to know how to list the graphs available.

The only non-empty graph I was able to run was `http://localhost:8890/sparql`

For example, in a relational database environment, I believe this kind of info could be retrieved from system tables.

Comment: Namespaces are not part of RDF or a triple store. What you mean are graphs. Graphs can contain resources that have IRIs with different namespaces. So the question would be "list all graphs in a triple store". Which leads to something like `select distinct ?g {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}}`.

Comment: `select * {graph ?g {}}` should work.

Comment: @AndyS, that returns `_star_fake: 1`

Comment: OP has been corrected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in comments, [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=%20%20SELECT%20%20DISTINCT%20%3Fg%20%0D%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%20%7B%20GRAPH%20%3Fg%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20%7D%20%0D%0AORDER+BY++%3Fg%0D%0A+++&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) will get you a list of all Named Graphs (which, as also noted, are not the same as "namespaces") in the targeted store --

```
  SELECT  DISTINCT ?g 
   WHERE  { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o} } 
ORDER BY  ?g
```

You can see live results (limited here to 100 graph names) on the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=%20%20SELECT%20%20DISTINCT%20%3Fg%20%0D%0A%20%20%20WHERE%20%20%7B%20GRAPH%20%3Fg%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20%7D%20%0D%0AORDER+BY++%3Fg%0D%0A+++LIMIT++100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) (a very short list, as you would expect) and on [URIBurner](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=++SELECT++DISTINCT+%3Fg+%0D%0A+++WHERE++%7B+GRAPH+%3Fg+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D+%7D+%0D%0AORDER+BY++%3Fg%0D%0A+++LIMIT++100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) (a much longer and more varied list).

Comment: wow ...  the query you hyperlinked to took like 10 sec to execute.  Virtuoso is not known for performance, which I also noted in the implementation I have to work with

Comment: The public endpoints to which I linked are open to the world, and are not typically answering only one query at a time, so *other* queries may impact performance on *your* query. Virtuoso is fairly well known for excellent performance, but this does require [proper tuning to its environment](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfgeneral/), and [properly built benchmarks](http://ldbcouncil.org/), among other considerations. I would guess that your own deployment needs some of that tuning, to start.

Comment: that query seems to work.  however, i created a new graph (`sparql { CREATE GRAPH <http://blah.blah/allTriples.ttl> }`), reran the query but the graph didn't show in the results.  is it because I didn't insert any data to it ?

Comment: I guess I just answered my own question by inserting some data and the answer is yes

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was facing the same problem and thought someone else might benefit from the solution I found.

I was trying to execute this query to list all graphs and it was taking about 5 minutes to return a result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?g 
WHERE { 
  GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o}
}
```

Instead, you should try the following query suggested in [this documentation from Virtuoso](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideAllGraphs):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?g 
WHERE { 
  GRAPH ?g {?s a ?o}
}
```

This query finished in less than 1 second and returned the list of graphs in the store. Of course, this query would only return graphs which have at least one triple with the predicate `rdf:type`, but it's still a big improvement on the one suggested by TallTed.

Comment: this query works for AWS Neptune too. In Neptune Notebook (a jupyter notebook connected to the graph DB), the result is a single DefaultNamedGraph.
http://aws.amazon.com/neptune/vocab/v01/DefaultNamedGraph

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. It's really weird that they don't index things to support this basic use case in the general form of `?s ?p ?o`.